# Subsetting datasets with unequal number of observations in R

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have a dataset of movies in R with over 5,000 observations and another dataset of movies with the books they're based on that has just over 1,600 observations. I want to combine the datasets and subset it to only the movies that were based on books.

Here are a couple sample datalines from the movies dataset:

```
movie_title      duration    gross     content_rating    year
Avatar           178       760505847     PG-13           2009
The Jungle Book  106       362645141     PG              2016
```

And a couple from the books dataset:

```
movie_title                         book        author          released
Hunger Games: Mockingjay, Part 2    Mockingjay  Suzanne Collins 2015
Insurgent                           Insurgent   Veronica Roth   2015
```

I only care about the movie_titles that they have in common.
I tried to merge the two datasets by movie title and it says there are 0 observations.

```
movies<-merge(imdb.movies,booklist, by="movie_title")
```

I've also tried filtering it with this code:

```
filter(imdb.movies, imdb.movies$movie_title==booklist$movie_title)
```

And combining them with this code:

```
    combined_movies<- imdb.movies[imdb.movies$movie_title==booklist$movie_title]
```

None of these seem to work. Is there a way to compare if `imdb.movies$movie_title==booklist$movie_title` and only keep the observations that are the same?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want `intersect(imdb.movies$movie_title, booklist$movie_title)`. Once you have the intersection of the two lists, you can subset either dataset to observations having movie titles in the intersect.

Comment: are there _partial_ matching? or are move_titles supposed to match _exactly_ between the two datasets? Your code for merging seems fine to me. If the result is 0 observations, then it's likely that there are no movie_titles that match _exactly_

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr you could use:

```
inner_join(imdb.movies,booklist)
```

Assumes that the `movie_title` column name in both data frames are identical and that the move name / book names are identical.

Comment: Wouldn't that just give the same result as `merge(imdb.movies,booklist, by="movie_title")`?

Comment: Haven't used merge in quite a while, just had to have a quick look but you're probably right. Added a caveat to my answer regarding 'exact match'.